# Unrecognized VM option 'ShenandoahGCHeuristics=compact'

Tags: java, macos, virtual-machine, shenandoah

On mac I am trying to use Shenandoah on java with the flags:

`-XX:ShenandoahGCHeuristics=compact and  -XX:+UseShenandoahGC`

and I get the same error on java 13 and 12:

> Unrecognized VM option 'ShenandoahGCHeuristics=compact' Error: Could
>   not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has
>   occurred. Program will exit.

and the error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Option -XX:+UseShenandoahGC
>   not supported

Does anyone know the reason for this or how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/19/not-all-openjdk-12-builds-include-shenandoah-heres-why/

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you are using the OpenJDK binary that does not include Shenandoah. Today, the only vendor who does not ship Shenandoah in their binaries is [Oracle](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/19/not-all-openjdk-12-builds-include-shenandoah-heres-why/) (those builds you get at jdk.java.net). Try to pick up any other OpenJDK distribution: your OS package manager, AdoptOpenJDK, SAPMachine, Amazon Corretto, etc.